# Size-bias coupling, poisson approximation, telescoping sum

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Good day

I was reading [this lecture](http://www.i-journals.org/ps/viewarticle.php?id=182&layout=abstract). I don't understand the proof of theorem $4.13$, which is on page $252$.

> Theorem 4.13: Let $W \ge 0$ be an integer-valued random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[W] = \lambda > 0$ and let $W^s$ be size-bias coupling of $W$. If $Z$ has $Poi(\lambda)$ distribution, then
>
> $$d(W,Z)_{TV} \le \min\{1,\lambda\}\mathbb{E}|W + 1 - W^s|$$
>
> where $d(W,Z)_{TV}$ stands for total variation distance of distributions of $W$ and $Z$.

In the proof I understand everything apart from the following step:

$\lambda | \mathbb{E}(f(W+1) - f(W^s)) |  \le \lambda |\Delta f| \mathbb{E} | W + 1 - W^s|$

Where $\Delta f (k) := f(k+1)-f(k)$ and $f$ is bounded. The author says: "rewrite $f(W+1)-f(W)$ as a telescoping sum of $|W + 1 - W^s|$ terms." Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Actually, the aut(h)or says to rewrite $f(W+1)-f(W^s)$ as a telescoping sum of $|W + 1 - W^s|$ terms, which makes sense.

Comment: Hey Did and thank you for your reply. It might make sense to you, but i just don't see how i can represent $f(W+1)-f(W^s)$ as a telescoping sum of $|W +1 -W^s|$ terms. Can you write it out?

Comment: $f(5+1)-f(2)=(f(6)-f(5))+(f(5)-f(4))+(f(4)-f(3))+(f(3)-f(2))$ with $4=(5+1)-2$ terms.

Comment: Did, thank you very much once again. After your comment i could understand what the author meant by his sentence and have completed the proof.